# iCarousel custom view xib changes subview width automatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, icarousel

I'm trying to add a custom view to the iCarousel view using XIB UI, but when initialized and run, the width of the subview of carousel view changes automatically.

[image][image]

```
func carousel(carousel: iCarousel!, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView! {

    var itemView: ProfileQuestionView

    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil) {

        itemView    =   UINib.init(nibName: "ProfileQuestionView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! ProfileQuestionView
        itemView.frame              =  CGRect.init(x: 20, y: 10, width: self.view.frame.width-40, height: self.carouselView.frame.height-20)

        itemView.layer.borderColor  =  UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        itemView.layer.borderWidth  =  0.5
        itemView.layer.cornerRadius =  5.0;
        itemView.layoutIfNeeded()

    } else {

        //get a reference to the label in the recycled view
        itemView = view as! ProfileQuestionView

        itemView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    return itemView
}
```

Don't know why this issue is appearing.

```
carouselView.type = iCarouselType.Rotary
```

Comment: Give a tag to your item view `itemView.tag = 1` after creating from nib and in `else` block fetch by tag `itemView = (view?.viewWithTag(1))!`. See if that fixes the problem. No need to call `layoutIfNeeded`

Answer (score 0):

Its just a hit and try. Not sure it will work.

Try changing your this line

```
itemView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 20, y: 10, width: self.view.frame.width-40, height: self.carouselView.frame.height-20)
```

to

```
itemView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 20, y: 10, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width-40, height: self.carouselView.frame.height-20)
```

As if your are reloading your carousel in `viewDidLoad` the constraints are still not set yet.

Also try getting your item by tag.

```
if (view == nil) {
     itemView = UINib.init(nibName: "ProfileQuestionView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! ProfileQuestionView

    // give a tag
    itemView.tag = 1
    //Then your rest of the code
    } else {
     // Reusability
     itemView = (view?.viewWithTag(1))!
}
```

Hopefully that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue on Xcode 8, but my code can work well on Xcode 7.3.1.
Put your initialize carousel in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        //Check if carousel is initialized or not
        if self.carousel.dataSource == nil {
            //Init your carousel here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize type of the carousel in viewDidLayoutSubviews()

> **Method *viewDidLayoutSubviews()***

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // carousel type
    yourCarouselName.type = .custom
}
```